# Error 400 (Bad Request) while creating S3 Bucket with CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I am following the Amazon Chime SDK workshop and I came accross this problem while creating a bucket with their provided template.

CLI:
`aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name chimesdk-ws-102-s3-cfd --template-body file://csdk-ws-102-s3-cfd.yml`

Template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: 'CloudFront distribution with an S3 origin for Amazon ChimeSDK WS-102'

Resources:
  S3Bucket:
    DeletionPolicy: 'Delete'
    Metadata:
      Comment: 'Bucket to store some data for chimesdk-workshops'
    Properties:
      AccessControl: 'Private'
      BucketName: !Sub 's3-origin-chimesdk-workshops-${AWS::StackName}-${AWS::AccountId}-${!RandomDigits 3}'
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'

  S3BucketPolicy:
    Metadata:
      Comment: 'Bucket policy to allow CloudFront to access S3'
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref S3Bucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action:
              - 's3:GetObject'
            Effect: 'Allow'
            Principal:
              CanonicalUser: !GetAtt CfOriginAccessIdentity.S3CanonicalUserId
            Resource:
              - !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::${S3Bucket}/*'
    Type: 'AWS::S3::BucketPolicy'

  CfDistribution:
    Metadata:
      Comment: 'CloudFront distribution with an S3 origin for Amazon ChimeSDK WS-102'
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        Comment: 'CloudFront distribution with an S3 origin for Amazon ChimeSDK WS-102'
        DefaultCacheBehavior:
          AllowedMethods:
            - 'HEAD'
            - 'GET'
          CachedMethods:
            - 'HEAD'
            - 'GET'
          Compress: false
          DefaultTTL: 86400
          ForwardedValues:
            Cookies:
              Forward: 'none'
            Headers:
              - 'Origin'
            QueryString: false
          MaxTTL: 31536000
          MinTTL: 86400
          TargetOriginId: !Sub 's3-origin-${S3Bucket}'
          ViewerProtocolPolicy: 'redirect-to-https'
        DefaultRootObject: 'index.html'
        Enabled: true
        HttpVersion: 'http1.1'
        IPV6Enabled: false
        Origins:
          - DomainName: !GetAtt S3Bucket.DomainName
            Id: !Sub 's3-origin-${S3Bucket}'
            OriginPath: ''
            S3OriginConfig:
              OriginAccessIdentity: !Sub 'origin-access-identity/cloudfront/${CfOriginAccessIdentity}'
        PriceClass: 'PriceClass_All'
    Type: 'AWS::CloudFront::Distribution'

  CfOriginAccessIdentity:
    Metadata:
      Comment: 'Access S3 bucket content only through CloudFront'
    Properties:
      CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityConfig:
        Comment: 'Access S3 bucket content only through CloudFront'
    Type: 'AWS::CloudFront::CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity'

Outputs:
  S3BucketName:
    Description: 'Bucket name'
    Value: !Ref S3Bucket
  CfDistributionId:
    Description: 'Id for CloudFront distribution with an S3 origin for Amazon ChimeSDK WS-102'
    Value: !Ref CfDistribution
  CfDistributionDomainName:
    Description: 'Domain name for CloudFront distribution with an S3 origin for Amazon ChimeSDK WS-102'
    Value: !GetAtt CfDistribution.DomainName
```

Error:

> Bad Request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad Request; Request ID: HYNPE7QQSABRN1ZV; S3 Extended Request ID: kmLUHBpmYN1ZQ9OJ928MgY+ZsbrzLmKm74v2m3K0NbPiF/dKWgA6rrDP9criO/rdUQAVKHoY1F0=; Proxy: null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bucket name is incorrect. There is no such thing as `${!RandomDigits 3}` in CloudFormation. You have to explicitly specify those random digits.

Comment: Thank you. Removing `${!RandomDigits 3}` and changing the bucket name solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to a permission issue. Check the following two locations for a more verbose exception:

1. Cloudformation stack events in the CFN Web Console, it should tell you exactly what failed and why.
2. If the above still states `Bad Request`, then check Cloudtrail logs for exceptions at the same time you launched the stack.

Comment: Yes, the stack event shows bucket creation failed due to `Bad Request`. 

Is it still possible for it to be a permission issue despite doing this through CloudShell as the root user?

Comment: Not if you're root user of the account. I'd lean more towards Marcins answer, unless you specifically set up a function to resolve the unique identifiers for the S3 bucket. Where are you following the tutorial?

Comment: I am following the [Building with Amazon Chime SDK using React](https://workshops.aws/categories/Amazon%20Chime%20SDK?tag=Lambda) workshop for Amazon Chime SDK.

They provide the template file [here](https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/workshops/de1c7d2d-6826-44db-a678-ff7a62747ec4/en-US/40-an-s3-web-server/41-lambda-web-server)

Comment: Thanks. I'll get the issue resolved.